# Trying to pass url anchor to controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get the following error when trying to pass the anchor of a url to a controller:

```
No route matches {:action=>"feed_index", :controller=>"feed"} missing required keys: [:anchor]
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Feed", feed_feed_index_path(@feed_index, :anchor => "12345") %>
```

FeedController.rb

```
class FeedController < ApplicationController

  def feed_index
    @picture = Picture.where(:number => params[:anchor])
  end

end
```

Routes.rb

```
get "/feed/feed_index/:anchor" => "feed#feed_index", :as => :feed_feed_index
```

Comment: @Зелёный Didn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails look at `:anchor` key in the url and thinks what is an another parameter.

Fix your routes to:

```
get "/feed/feed_index/:feed_index" => "feed#feed_index", :as => :feed_feed_index
```

Use the same url helper:

```
<%= link_to "Feed", feed_feed_index_path(@feed_index, :anchor => "12345") %>
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    "/feed/feed_index"   :feed_index   #anchor
```

Generate link:

```
http://localhost:3000/feed/feed_index/1#12345
```

Tested.

Read about [routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#generating-paths-and-urls-from-code)

Comment: I had to change `feed_feed_index_path(@feed_index, :anchor => "12345")` to `feed_feed_index_path(:feed_index, :anchor => "12345")`, then it worked

Comment: @Senju looks like `@feed_index` is `nil` here. i tested with `feed_feed_index_path(1, anchor: "12345")`

Comment: Yea, that makes sense. Also, I up voted you ! Thanks.

Comment: One more thing... in my controller, `params[:anchor]` doesn't seem to be grabbing the "12345"

Comment: b'cause `anchor` it's not a `parameter`, `anchor` used for navigation on page, it's `id` for some div for pint it.

Comment: Well, that was kind of the whole point of this... Is there anyway to make it a parameter?

Comment: pass it as `params` `feed_feed_index_path(:feed_index, params: { :anchor => "12345") }`

Comment: Oh my god thank you! I have been trying to get this to work for 2 days

Comment: My pleasure, Happy coding!